# How to access a random element in a dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, random

I got the following code:

```
var myDic = [String: Customer]()
let s1 = Customer("nameee", "email1")
let s2 = Customer("nameee2", "email2")
let s3 = Customer("nameee3", "email3")
myDic[s1.name] = s1
myDic[s2.name] = s2
myDic[s3.name] = s3
```

How can I select a random element from the dictionary? I think I should use arc4random_uniform but couldn't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to cast some things around, but this seems to work.

```
var dict:[String:Int] = ["A":123, "B": 234, "C": 345]
let index: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(dict.count)))
let randomVal = Array(dict.values)[index] # 123 or 234 or 345
```

Basically, generate a random index value between zero and the total item count. Get the values of the dictionary as an array and then fetch the random index.

You could even wrap that in an extension for easy access.

Comment: What about changing that last line to...

let randomVal = dict.values.array[index]

I checked and they seem to perform the same. Just thought I would mention it.

Comment: Hmm I don't think the provided code is valid Swift anymore - the following worked for me:  let randomVal = dict.values.array[index]

Comment: The last line works for me and I'm in XCode 7 Beta 5.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4.2+ (Xcode 10+) introduces two simple possibilities.

Either [randomElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/values/2995315-randomelement):

```
let randomVal = myDict.values.randomElement()
```

Or [randomElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995361-randomelement):

```
let randomVal = myDict.randomElement().value
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5+ (Xcode 12+) introduces randomise *Dictionary* **key** also

```
let randomVal = myDict.randomElement()?.key
```