# Random Elements from Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, random, element, indexof

Here is my Array of Dictionary,

```
var myArrayOfDict =  [["vegetables": ["CARROT","BEANS"], "fruits": ["APPLE","MANGO","BANANA"], "letters":["A","B","C","D"],"numbers":["ONE","TWO","THREE"],"shapes":["SQUARE","RECTANGLE","CIRCLE"]]]
```

How do i get the desired output, actually i need to get random selected elements of the specified range ...(i.e) when i need 3 elements randomnly from dictionary as like,

```
[["fruits": ["APPLE","MANGO","BANANA"],"shapes":["SQUARE","RECTANGLE","CIRCLE"],"numbers":["ONE","TWO","THREE"]]]
```

When i need just 2 elements randomnly like,

```
[["shapes":["SQUARE","RECTANGLE","CIRCLE"],"fruits": ["APPLE","MANGO","BANANA"]]]
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50733384/429555

Comment: Thanks for the reference link provided, i have seen and not sure how to apply it on my requirement. It is array of dictionary of type [[String:[String]]],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution using `randomElement()`.

```
func randomSelection(from dict: [String: [String]], count: Int) -> [String: [String]] {    
    guard !dict.isEmpty else { return [:] }

    var result = [String: [String]]()

    for i in 0..<count {
        let element = dict.randomElement()! //We know dictionary is not empty
        result[element.key] = element.value  
    }
    return result
}
```

The above solution might return less elements in a dictionary than expected if the same element is returned more than once from `randomElemnt()`. If this should be voided the below solution should work

```
func randomSelection(from dict: [String: [String]], count: Int) -> [String: [String]] {
    guard !dict.isEmpty else { return [:] }
    guard dict.count > count else { return dict }

    var result = [String: [String]]()

    while result.count < count {
        let element = dict.randomElement()!
        if result[element.key] == nil { 
            result[element.key] = element.value        
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Since the function takes a dictionary as the first argument the array needs to be looped over

```
for d in myArrayOfDict {
    print(randomSelection(from: d, count: 2))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array` `myArrayOfDict` contains a single `Dictionary`. So, it doesn't make sense getting a random element from it.

As your example explains, you need to get random elements from the `Dictionary` itself.

So, you can use **`randomElement`** to get that working.

```
let myArrayOfDict =  ["vegetables": ["CARROT","BEANS"], "fruits": ["APPLE","MANGO","BANANA"], "letters":["A","B","C","D"],"numbers":["ONE","TWO","THREE"],"shapes":["SQUARE","RECTANGLE","CIRCLE"]]

var elements = [String : [String]]()
let count = 2
for _ in 0..<count {
    if let element = myArrayOfDict.randomElement() {
        elements[element.key] = element.value
    }
}
print(elements)
```